# Updating uploaded image URL in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the uploaded image URL in MySQL database `WHERE UserName='$username'`but nothing happens.

I have double checked my code but there wasn't any error but still not working.

**Hint**

1. `$user_name` is the session. `$user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['UserName']);`
2. `$con` is the connection

**Php codes**

```
function uploadImageFile($user_name) { // Note: GD library is required for this function

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $iJpgQuality = 100;

    if ($_FILES) {
        // if no errors and size less than 250kb
        if (! $_FILES['image_file']['error'] && $_FILES['image_file']['size'] < 250 * 1024) {
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])) {
                if (!is_dir('avatar')) {
                    mkdir('avatar');
                }
                // new unique filename
                $sTempFileName = 'avatar/' . md5(time().rand());
                // move uploaded file into cache folder
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $sTempFileName);

                // change file permission to 644
                @chmod($sTempFileName, 0644);

                $sResultFileName = copyImageFile('avatar/'.$user_name.'', $sTempFileName, 200, 200, $iJpgQuality);
                if ($sResultFileName) {

                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ara") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

                $avatar1=copyImageFile('avatar1/'.$user_name.'', $sTempFileName, 500, 500);
                $avatar2=copyImageFile('avatar2/'.$user_name.'', $sTempFileName, 700, 700);

                mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE profiles SET (AvatarImage,AvatarImageBig,AvatarImageSmall) = ('".$sResultFileName."','".$avatar1."','".$avatar2."') WHERE UserName = '$user_name'");   


                    @unlink($sTempFileName);

                    return $sResultFileName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
}

function copyImageFile($dirName, $originImageName, $iWidth, $iHeight, $iJpgQuality = 90) {
if (file_exists($originImageName) && filesize($originImageName) > 0) {        
    $aSize = getimagesize($originImageName); // try to obtain image info
    if (!$aSize) {
        @unlink($originImageName);
        return;
    }

    // check for image type
    switch($aSize[2]) {
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $sExt = '.jpg';
            $vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($originImageName);
            break;
        /*case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $sExt = '.gif';

            // create a new image from file 
            $vImg = @imagecreatefromgif($sTempFileName);
            break;*/
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $sExt = '.png';
            $vImg = @imagecreatefrompng($originImageName);
            break;
        default:
            @unlink($originImageName);
            return;
    }

    // create a new true color image
    $vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight );

    // copy and resize part of an image with resampling
    imagecopyresampled($vDstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, (int)$_POST['x1'], (int)$_POST['y1'], $iWidth, $iHeight, (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);

    // define a result image filename        
    if (!is_dir($dirName)) {
        mkdir($dirName);
    }
    $newImageName = $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(time().rand()) . $sExt;

    // output image to file
    imagejpeg($vDstImg, $newImageName, $iJpgQuality);
    //@unlink($sTempFileName);

    return $newImageName;
}

return false;
}

$user_name = $_SESSION['UserName'];

$sImage = uploadImageFile($user_name);
echo '<img src="'.$sImage.'" />';
```

Comment: You have some checks, first of all use `empty()` better practice. and also do a couple of `else` with an error message so you can easily detect the issue.

Comment: please use mysqli_error() to get the error message after mysqli_query() and add it to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your database connection and query script:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ara") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Here you have a not declared $link variable. It should be $con. Anyway you can not call mysqli_error($con) if you don't have a successful connection. You should better test your connection like:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ara");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Your update query should be:

```
"UPDATE profiles SET AvatarImage = '".$sResultFileName."', AvatarImageBig = '".$avatar1."',AvatarImageSmall = '".$avatar2."' WHERE UserName = '$user_name'"
```

instead of

```
,"UPDATE profiles SET (AvatarImage,AvatarImageBig,AvatarImageSmall) = ('".$sResultFileName."','".$avatar1."','".$avatar2."') WHERE UserName = '$user_name'"
```

And of course you have to check the errors from mysqli as already commented.

Comment: Good it updates but all my database connection information is in mysql.php, and i want to include it in this page instead of writing connection details in every page.

Comment: And when i add include connect/mysql.php it says `undefined variable con` .

Comment: You are using `$con` in the function `uploadImageFile($user_name)`, so you should pass the variable `$con` to this function, something like `uploadImageFile($user_name, $con)` of course then you have to change your functions accepted arguments